# Calculate column quantity total in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects that contain a quantity field. I'm looking to total one field from the array on a review screen on a table.

I have an array of administrations populated with object fields and the one I'm looking to calculate is the 'quantity field'.

```
<tr class="primary" *ngFor="let medication of sachets">
    <td>{{medication.administration.quantity}}</td>
    <td>
        {{medication.medicationName}}
        <p class="instructions">{{medication.additionalInstructions}}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Within the table, I am calculating the length of entries using angulars .length

I'm looking to calculate a total for the array of quantities.

Comment: You'll need a function that accesses each quantity and sums them up. Here's a native JS example: [Patrick Leib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63681334/14956277) to [Better way to sum a property value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247859/better-way-to-sum-a-property-value-in-an-array). This function can either be in your component code or directly in your template.

Comment: So what's the problem you're running into? If you're trying to do the total in the template, I'd suggest setting a property with the total in the component code instead and binding that to the template so you're not looping through the array on each digest cycle.

Comment: You could also implement a pipe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164896/angular-2-pipe-calculating-summary-of-array-of-objects

Comment: @adam0101 the issue is looping through each quantity field to total it, the field is within an array of objects and I'm just looking to calculate the total of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to filter and add the values. I used the .map function to create an array of quantity values, and using .reduce, add them together to give the desired total.

```
totalFunction() {
  const initialValue = 0;
  this.totalQuantity = this.administered.map
  (item => item.administration.quantity).reduce(
  (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue,
  initialValue);
  console.log(this.totalQuantity);
}
```